# Specific ports are open|filted after configure Firewall Rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

I have configured network target in VM and Firewall Rules as below:

[image]

[image]

then disable Windows Firewall:

[image]

Port scan results:

[image]

Anything wrong. Why those ports are not "OPEN"?

Appreciate any help and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions regarding email ports described here [1]. Basically ports 25, 465 and 587 are blocked. The tutorial does provide alternatives, you can use other ports, a relay server or a third party provider to handle IP reputation.

Best, 
Miguel.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/